# PHP - UTF-16 to UTF-8(hex) conversion

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

Is it possible to convert UTF-16
`U+610F`
style character to UTF-8 (hex)
`E6848F`
using PHP ?

UTF-8 character is '意'

Comment: Unicode is not encoding. Encondings are UTF-16 (first case) and UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments in the [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) man page, one quick hack for turning an ordinal character number into a UTF-8 byte sequence:

```
function unichr($u) {
    return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
}

// unichr(0x610F) -> "\xE6\x84\x8F"
```

Comment: I get utf8's '意', not "\xE6\x84\x8F". How did you get "\xE6\x84\x8F"?

Comment: The byte string `"\xE6\x84\x8F"` (ie. the byte 0xE6, followed by the byte 0x84, then 0x8F), interpreted as UTF-8, is `意`. I put it in string literal escapes so you could see what you're really getting.

Comment: But i need get string `"\xE6\x84\x8F"`. Is it possible from this solution?

Comment: The string `"\xE6\x84\x8F"` **is** `意`! Are you saying you want to see the actual hex codes of those bytes? Then use `bin2hex` on the string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

Answer (score 0):

php have unicode encoding and decoding.. let u try on that

```
utf8_decode(); or utf8_encode();
```