# Convert Unicode hex value to bytes with PHP

Tags: php

I need to convert characters, like U+0123 (the Latin Small Letter G With Cedilla) to the appropriate UTF8 hex-encoded bytes like this 0xC4 0xA3 (or c4a3). I know there's a function (or combination of functions) I can use to accomplish this in PHP, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: I guess it might be easier to help you with that function if you at least mentioned its name...

Comment: I was trying to mess with the code provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670039/php-utf-16-to-utf-8hex-conversion: mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($u) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');, but despite using bin2hex on the result I didn't get the bytes I'm aiming for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in [the answer you are linking to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670039/php-utf-16-to-utf-8hex-conversion) works fine as is but you must take some things into account:

- The function expects a number (e.g. `0x0123`) not a string (`'U+0123'`)
- Your output must be **displayed** as UTF-8
- You *may* need to call `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` (I've found that some systems have a wrong default)

Whatever, I've written a little variation that accepts a Unicode code point in case that's exactly what you need:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

function unicode_code_point_to_char($code_point) {
    if( preg_match('/^U\+(\d{4,6})$/', $code_point, $matches) ){
        return mb_convert_encoding('&#' . hexdec($matches[0]) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

echo unicode_code_point_to_char('U+0123');
```

## Update:

I've just noticed that I have misread your question. Try this:

```
function unicode_code_point_to_hex_string($code_point) {
    if( preg_match('/^U\+(\d{4,6})$/', $code_point, $matches) ){
        return bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding('&#' . hexdec($matches[0]) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'));
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}
```